# If else condition with select inside SQL

Tags: sql

Hello I am not sure about my query :

```
IF((SELECT table2.active FROM table2) = 0)
    SELECT table2.price FROM table2
ELSE IF ((SELECT table2.active FROM table2) = 1)
          SELECT table1.price FROM table1
```

I try to use case statement but I don't have the good results.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN table2.active = 0
        THEN (SELECT table2.price)
        WHEN table2.active = 1
        THEN (SELECT table1.def_price)
   END AS price
```

FROM table2, table1;

I am new in SQL.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your question by adding sample data and expected output as text to the question together with an explanation of what you are trying to achieve (reverse engineering from non working code would  be guesswork) AND mysql and sqlserver are not the same thing and don't share many features so please remove the inappropriate tag,

Comment: What RDBMS are you really using? SQL Server and MySQL are 2 very different products. The above code also implies that your table `table2` only has 1 row in it, which I somewhat doubt. As for a `Case` (`Switch`) statement SQL Server does not support these, only `CASE` expressions. I don't know if this is true for MySQL as I'm not a user of it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are writing is not semantically valid SQL.  Essentially, you are asking "give me all the active rows from table2", assuming there is only one, and expecting an if/then/else statement to do some logic based on the result.

If you only actually have one row in the table, you can potentially make this work by adding TOP 1 into the query (but there are other reasons you don't likely want to do just that):

SELECT TOP 1 table2.active FROM table2

Assuming this makes you statement "work" functionally, you probably want to use a variable to store the value.  Otherwise you are running the query twice in the case of the else block which is not ideal.  Queries are relatively expensive as they work on sets and can read from disk.  It is best when you do set-based operations on them.

You probably should step back and ask why you would store some data in table 1 or table 2 based on the value.  Also ask if you are trying to do this in a loop over multiple values.  SQL works best when you can do an operation over a whole set of rows at once.

There are several good SQL books out there from which you can learn if you are new to SQL.   Ultimately, mixing procedural and set-based operations like this is a common issue for those new to the language.  With a little work, you can train your brain to think in set theory and use the full power of SQL to help you.

Best of luck!

Comment: *"SELECT TOP 1 table2.active FROM table2"* without an `ORDER BY` this will simply return any arbitrary row from the table, which may or may not be the row the OP wants and could easily not be consistent each time the query is run.

Answer (score 0):

This is like IF ELSE. If there is not need for ELSE... you can replace the second WHEN with ELSE and erase the "ELSE 'no value available'". Don't forget the END ;)
You need to join from one table to another with a key value like the primary and foreign key or another key constraint.
The WHERE clause is optional.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t2.active = 0 THEN t2.price WHEN t2.active = 1 THEN t1.price ELSE 'no value available' END as Result
    FROM table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.KeyValue=t2.KeyValue
        WHERE...
```

Or if you want every row from one table with every row from the other, you can try this...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t2.active = 0 THEN t2.price WHEN t2.active = 1 THEN t1.price ELSE 'no value available' END as Result
    FROM table2 t2, table1 t1
        WHERE...
```

*edit Sorry for the bad formatting. I am completely new here.